# Responsive Full Width Section

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

Can someone take a look at my website and help me fix how a section looks while viewed on a mobile device. The "Thousands of Canadians" and "Mobile Search" sections on the homepage are not responsive like the rest of the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Below is the CSS i have inserted so far:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px){
#site > .wrapper, #footer > .wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
}
```

www.jobspark.ca

Comment: your domain expired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are targeting the right part, if you look at the columns those are in, there are `.myLeftColumn` and `.myRightColumn` divs that have the original percentage widths. Try changing both of those to 100% width when the screen is smaller than 640px or whenever you need a breakpoint.

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
    .sqs-block-content .myLeftColumn,
    .sqs-block-content .myRightColumn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks for that. I totally over looked that. One las question. Can you see a way to fix my logo while viewing on phone. It wants to act like a fixed navigation and slides down the screen while scrolling. Hopefully that makes sense www.jobspark.ca

Comment: Checked on an iphone and didn't notice the issue you are talking about with the logo other than it being slightly cut-off by the nav menu.

Comment: I am just trying to get the logo to appear inside the Navigation at the top.